# An error with my custom listview and my database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a SQLite Database inside my application and I need to get data out of my database and put these data inside a custom listview I made. This listview is inside my Games fragment, which I use for my Viewpager activity (So you'll be able to swipe through the activies) I wrote all the code for it, but when I run my application, my app keeps crashing and giving me the same crash-report.

It would be great if there would be a way to fix it.

**Crash-report:**

```
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.example.gamenity.DBHelper.getAllGames(DBHelper.java:122)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.example.gamenity.Games.onCreateView(Games.java:40)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
```

**DBHelper.class**

```
package com.example.gamenity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // database
    private static final String DB_NAME = "GamenityDB";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 6;
    // tabellen
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "Users";
    private static final String TABLE_GAMES = "Games";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "userID";
    private static final String CREATE_USERS =
            "create table Users(userID integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "username text not null, password text not null, email text not null, gender text, DOB text, picture BLOB);";
    public static final String FLD_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String FLD_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String FLD_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String FLD_GENDER = "gender";

    private static final String CREATE_GAMES =
            "create table Games (gameID integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "Title varchar(255) not null, Description text not null, Genre text not null, Release date null, PS4 text null, " +
                    "PS3 text null, X1 text null, X360 text null, WiiU text null, PC text null, gamePicture blob null);";
    public static final String FLD_TITLE = "Title";
    public static final String FLD_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String FLD_GENRE = "Genre";
    public static final String FLD_RELEASE = "Release";
    public static final String FLD_PS4 = "PS4";
    public static final String FLD_PS3 = "PS3";
    public static final String FLD_X1 = "X1";
    public static final String FLD_X360 = "X360";
    public static final String FLD_WiiU = "WiiU";
    public static final String FLD_PC = "PC";
    public static final String FLD_GAMEIMAGE = "gamePicture";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_GAMES);
   }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GAMES);        
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // database functies
    public void createUser(String naam, String pw, String mail, String gender) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FLD_USERNAME, naam);
        values.put(FLD_PASSWORD, pw);
        values.put(FLD_EMAIL, mail);
        values.put(FLD_GENDER, gender);
        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void createGame(String title, String description,String genre, String release, 
                            String PS4, String PS3, String X1, String X360, String WiiU, String PC, byte[] gamePicture) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FLD_TITLE, title);
        values.put(FLD_DESCRIPTION, description);
        values.put(FLD_GENRE, genre);
        values.put(FLD_RELEASE, release);
        values.put(FLD_PS4, PS4);
        values.put(FLD_PS3, PS3);
        values.put(FLD_X1, X1);
        values.put(FLD_X360, X360);
        values.put(FLD_WiiU, WiiU);
        values.put(FLD_PC, PC);
        values.put(FLD_GAMEIMAGE, gamePicture);
        db.insert(TABLE_GAMES, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Game> getAllGames() {
        ArrayList<Game> ArrayGames = new ArrayList<Game>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_GAMES + " ORDER BY Release";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Game Game = new Game(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getBlob(1));
                ArrayGames.add(Game);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return ArrayGames;
    }
```

**Game.class**

```
    package com.example.gamenity;

public class Game {
    private String title, description, genre, release, PS3, PS4, X1, X360, WiiU, PC;
    private byte[] image;

    public Game(String title, String description, String genre, String release,
                String PS3, String PS4, String X1, String X360, String WiiU, String PC, byte[] image ) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.release = release;
        this.PS3 = PS3;
        this.PS4 = PS4;
        this.X1 = X1;
        this.X360 = X360;
        this.WiiU = WiiU;
        this.PC = PC;
        this.image = image;
    }

    //Getters
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;    
    }

    public String getRelease() {
        return this.release;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return this.genre;
    }

    public String getPS3() {
        return this.PS3;
    }

    public String getPS4() {
        return this.PS4;
    }

    public String getX1() {
        return this.X1;
    }

    public String getX360() {
        return this.X360;
    }

    public String getWiiU() {
        return this.WiiU;
    }

    public String getPC() {
        return this.PC;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }
}
```

**ListviewGamesAdapter.class(My custom adapter for my listview)**

```
package com.example.gamenity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListviewGamesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Game>{
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Game> GamesArrayList;

    public ListviewGamesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Game> GamesArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_row_games, GamesArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.GamesArrayList = GamesArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_games, parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        TextView Title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView Genre= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView Description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);


        // 4. Set the text for textView 
        Title.setText(GamesArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        Description.setText(GamesArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
        Genre.setText(GamesArrayList.get(position).getGenre());

        // 5. return rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**list_row_games.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- Left side Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/stroke"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_picture"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Genre -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:text="Genre"
        android:textColor="@color/midGray"
        android:textSize="12dip" />

    <!-- Description -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/follow"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/follow"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
        android:textSize="13dip" />

    <!-- Release date -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/release"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/genre"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Fall 2014"
        android:textColor="@color/midBlue"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/follow"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/genre"
        android:background="@drawable/button_follow"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/portal_stickman"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Games.class (My activity with the listview)**

```
package com.example.gamenity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Games extends Fragment {

    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getActivity());

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_games, container, false);

        Button btn_addGame = (Button)mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.addGame);
        ListView list_games = (ListView)mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.listviewGames);


        btn_addGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent intent_addGame = new Intent(getActivity(), AddGame.class);
                startActivity(intent_addGame);
            }
        });



       ListviewGamesAdapter adapter = new ListviewGamesAdapter(getActivity(), db.getAllGames());

        list_games.setAdapter(adapter);
        db.close();

        return mRelativeLayout;
    }

}
```

**Viewpager.class**

```
package com.example.gamenity;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Viewpager extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager);
        initialisePaging();
        ActionbarButtons();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {
        List<Fragment> pages = new Vector<Fragment>();
        pages.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Home.class.getName()));
        pages.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, News.class.getName()));
        pages.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Games.class.getName()));

        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), pages);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    public void ActionbarButtons() {
        ImageButton notifications_btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.notifications_button);

        notifications_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View view) {
                Intent notifications = new Intent(Viewpager.this, Notifications.class);
                startActivity(notifications);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.viewpager, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is on line 40 of `Game.java`?

Comment: can you tell us whats is in line SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224? Debugging and Logcat are your friends

Comment: Emmanuel -  This is on line 40: ListviewGamesAdapter adapter = new ListviewGamesAdapter(getActivity(), db.getAllGames());

Comment: anotherBug - That's something I don't understand either, because I have no 224 lines in my code. I got 153 lines in my DBHelper.class, that's it.

Comment: does public ArrayList<Game> getAllGames() return null or and ArrayList with values?

Comment: I have no idea. Where can I check it? (Sorry, but I'm just a beginner in Android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a context in order to get a database instance, but you passed the contstructor of DBHelper null.  You should not initialize the DBHelper until at least `onCreate`.  Instead of this:

```
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getActivity());
```

Do this:

```
DBHelper db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    db = new DBHelper(getActivity());

    //...   
}
```

Also, I believe you aren't accessing your cursor properly.  For example, `cursor.getBlob(1)` should return null because column 1 is TEXT.  Also, `cursor.getText(4)` should return null because column 4 is DATE.  Also, you can't store dates in SQLite, you should store them as long milliseconds.  Do something like this:

```
String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FLD_TITLE));
String customer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FLD_DESCRIPTION));
Date date = (Date)cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(FLD_RELEASE));
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(FLD_GAMEIMAGE));
//...

Game Game = new Game(title, customer, date, //etc);
ArrayGames.add(Game);
```

Comment: And where exactly should I put this? Do I have to edit it like: Game game = new Game(String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FLD_TITLE)), String description = etc...)

Comment: The error still occurs, but thank you for reporting these bugs! :)

Comment: In Logcat, can you double click this line and tell me what line it is `05-19 11:07:38.096: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.example.gamenity.DBHelper.getAllGames(DBHelper.java:122)`

Comment: Line 122: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I've been looking for this for 2 days  :D